# How to make global constant aliases to variables in C++

Tags: c++, reference, alias

I'm rather new to C++ so sorry for any egregious mistakes.

**Problem statement**

My code is for mathematical computations, so main.cpp/main.h does the setup, reads in parameters, etc., and then a separate file/header, call it driver.cpp/driver.h, does the computations.

To encapsulate the parameters, I make several user-defined datatypes, initialized them in main.cpp, and pass them to a function defined in driver.cpp. I would like for these parameters to be seen as constant to the functions within driver.cpp, and I would also like to alias them for readability. It would be nice to alias them *once* instead of within every function. Is this possible?

I've tried to make a simple example which illustrates *what I want*, even though it won't run because you can't use constant references the way I do below.

Idea of what I want:

**main.cpp**

```
struct myStruct_t{
    int a,b,c;
};

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    myStruct_t myStruct;
    myStruct.a=1;
    myStruct.b=2;
    myStruct.c=3;

    driver(myStruct);
}
```

**driver.cpp**

```
const int &a,&b,&c;
void func1();
void func2();

driver(const myStruct_t& myStruct){
    a = myStruct.a;
    b = myStruct.b;
    c = myStruct.c;     
    func1();
    func2();  
} 
void func1(){
    // do stuff with a,b,c
}
void func2(){
    // do stuff with a,b,c
}
```

On the other hand, it would work to implement driver as follows. I don't like it as much because I will need to copy the reference declaration within every function.

What works but I don't like very much:

**alt_driver.cpp**

```
void func1(const myStruct_t& myStruct);
void func2(const myStruct_t& myStruct);

driver(const myStruct_t& myStruct){ 
    func1(myStruct);
    func2(myStruct);  
}

void func1(const myStruct_t& myStruct){
    const int& a = myStruct.a;
    const int& b = myStruct.b;
    const int& c = myStruct.c;
    // do stuff with a,b,c
}

void func2(const myStruct_t& myStruct){
    const int& a = myStruct.a;
    const int& b = myStruct.b;
    const int& c = myStruct.c;
    // do stuff with a,b,c
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason that a pointer to const, rather than a const reference, might not serve?

Comment: Make driver an object.  Then you can make the constants member variables.

Comment: You seem to be using global variables to pass parameters. That's really not good practice to be honest. The way you don't like very much is really the way to go. Pass parameters using the parameter passing mechanism built in to functions.

Comment: @Galik The reason I'm trying to do this is because in my code there are up to 10 different functions which all require `a,b,c,d,e,...`, so I feel the code would be polluted with so many lines of `const int & a = ...`

Comment: The `const int& a = ... ` are completely unnecessary. Just use `myStruct.a = ...` etc

Comment: @Galik I'm not sure what you mean. I'm not trying to assign the values of myStruct -- those are fixed. I'm trying to use the values of myStruct in a readable way.

Comment: Well using global variables just to get shorter variable names isn't something I would recommend.

Comment: I am inclined to agree with @Galik. On the other hand, OP's approach at least has merit from a learning perspective. In view of his comments, OP might pursue his global approach for now. Later, as experience illuminates to OP the reason seasoned programmers usually avoid global variables, OP can fairly easily transition to the standard approach. Better, he will at that time intuitively *understand* the reason he is transitioning. My view is that OP is probably doing all right for now.

Comment: Global objects are rather educational. They are seldom very practical in larger programs but they have learning value. They afford the learning programmer an opportunity to contrast variable-data-segment mechanics against stack mechanics. (OP almost certainly has no idea yet what these mechanics are, nor will he have for a while; but the point is, having implicitly exercised both here affords OP the basis to learn these mechanics later. *This* in turn illuminates the reason a close-to-the-metal language like C++ even exists, when one might instead just have used Python or whatever.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a pointer to const, rather than a const reference, might serve, then something like the following might work. (For a practical solution, I have taken the liberty to separate common declarations into a header file, `driver.h`. This is standard C++ practice.)

**driver.h**

```
#ifndef DRIVER_H
#define DRIVER_H

struct myStruct_t{
    int a,b,c;
};
void driver(const myStruct_t&);
void func1();
void func2();

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "driver.h"

int main(int, char **){
    myStruct_t myStruct;
    myStruct.a=1;
    myStruct.b=2;
    myStruct.c=3;

    driver(myStruct);
}
```

**driver.cpp**

```
#include "driver.h"

const int *a0,*b0,*c0;

void driver(const myStruct_t& myStruct){
    a0 = &myStruct.a;
    b0 = &myStruct.b;
    c0 = &myStruct.c;
    func1();
    func2();
}
void func1(){
    const int& a = *a0;
    const int& b = *b0;
    const int& c = *c0;
    // do stuff with a,b,c, such as:
    int d = a+b+c;
    ++d;
}
void func2(){
    const int& a = *a0;
    const int& b = *b0;
    const int& c = *c0;
    // do stuff with a,b,c, such as:
    int d = a+b+c;
    ++d;
}
```

The above does quite nearly the same as your global reference, except that the address is stored and used explicitly. Indeed, the machine code generated is probably identical.

Notice incidentally that I have written `const int *a,*b,*c;` rather than `int *const a, *const b, *const c;`. The latter would have defined const pointers, which are often useful but are not what you wanted here. Here, rather, you wanted pointers to const.

Comment: Within `func1()`, I would compute the sum `myStruct.a+myStruct.b` with `*a+*b`, or would I use `a+b`?

Comment: You would use `*a+*b`. If you would prefer something more like `a+b`, tell me. It would take a little extra work but I could probably adapt the answer to suit.

Comment: If it's possible I would appreciate seeing that. The computations are very long and involve multiplication (*) as well, so it could become hard to read.

Comment: Okay. This will take a bit of work but it should also be instructive. Allow about 12 minutes. I will update my answer.

Comment: Answer updated. Is that closer to what you had in mind?

Comment: It is closer. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Unless performance is a factor, I would advise against relying on global references to variables. I would suggest accessing them using a functional interface.

```
// Create a namespace for driver.cpp 
// Put all the helper functions and data in the namespace.
namespace driver_ns
{
   myStruct_t const* myStructPtr = nullptr;

   int const& a()
   {
      return myStructPtr->a;
   }

   int const& b()
   {
      return myStructPtr->b;
   }

   int const& c()
   {
      return myStructPtr->c;
   }
}

using namesapce driver_ns;

void func1();
void func2();

driver(const myStruct_t& myStruct){
   myStructPtr = &myStruct;
    func1();
    func2();  
} 

void func1(){
    // do stuff with a,b,c, usig a(), b(), and c()
}
void func2(){
    // do stuff with a,b,c, usig a(), b(), and c()
}
```

If you need to access `a`, `b`, and `c` in multiple files, add the functional interface in a shared .h file and implement them in a file independent of the files where they are used.

Comment: Just to clarify, within `func1()`, I would compute `a+b` using `a()+b()`?

Comment: This would indeed be the more usual way of doing it. The other answer, which I have given, assumes that OP has an unstated reason to use a global variable.

Comment: Could you clarify why this is the usual or standard way of implementing it?

Comment: Yes, @RSahu is right. It would be usual to pass a local object from `driver()` to `func1()` and `func2()`. The local object would contain the references. I, or he, can show you how that works if you wish.

Comment: @RSahu Your solution is what I would use if I required global symbols. Also, your namespace usage is exemplary. However, OP mentions in comments that he would prefer to write `a+b` rather than something longer like `a()+b()`. I wonder if it is possible *to adapt* your approach to meet this preference. The question is just interesting; that's all. Unfortunately, I can think of no way to do it except by abusing preprocessing macros.

Comment: @thb, I am happy to hear my approach to solving the problem was appealing to you. If using `a+b` is is really important to the user, they can certainly use `int const& a = driver_ns::a();`. This idea is similar to what you proposed in your answer -- `int const& a = *a0;`